# How can I export a .obj single object's vertices relative to Object origin instead of World Origin?

Tags: export, import, origin, world, obj

When I move the default cube `-10m` on the X-axis and export the object as `.obj`, I get values for the cube's mesh relative to the World Origin.

[image]

Here are the mesh values relative to World Origin instead of relative to object origin.

```
# Blender 4.0.1
# www.blender.org
mtllib left-cube.mtl
o Cube.001
v -11.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -11.000000 1.000000 1.000000
v -11.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v -11.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
v -9.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -9.000000 1.000000 1.000000
v -9.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v -9.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
```

Which causes the origin of the cube to be misplaced when I import the object back into Blender. Is this expected behavior? Do other 3D programs behave the same? Is there a way how to tell Blender to ignore the object's location and keep the original origin of the object so that it imports in the center? Or do I have to program that myself or use another format? A workaround would be to use a wrapper function that would save the current location and reset the object's location temporarily to the World Origin, then do the export, and then move the object back to its previous location coordinates.

[image]